# How to create "fuzzy" material design type shadows on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, python, css, graphics

I can't seem to find out how shadows are created in material design, or how css does it. Specifically, I am curious how, if given a canvas, one would create the 'blur' part, using algorithms. Below is an example of what I would like to be able to create, it is especially visible under the red dot.

Edit: I am more interested in how the effect is achieved using algorithms, not presets in CSS etc.

[image: Desired effect]

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching for a way to display a shadow, you can use one of the following approaches:

- [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) CSS property.
- [A gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient) in CSS.
- An ordinary image, [usually](http://blog.pelicandd.com/article/57/image-formats-and-why-do-they-matter) PNG.
- A vector image, that is a SVG object.